# CSS dropdown on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a drop down navigation bar, this is what I've got.

html

```
<div class="navBar">
    <ul class="navBarStyles navBarWidth navBarMain"> 
        <li class="onSelect"><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>

        <ul class="navBarExtended">
            <li class="borderLeft"><a href="#">ExtraItem</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navBarExtra" id="floatRight">
            <li class="i-icon">Dropdown</li>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="#">SubItem1</a><li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubItem2</a><li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubItem3</a><li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
    </ul>

</div>
```

css

```
    a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    }
.headerContent{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navBar{
    font-family: "opensans-regular";
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 48px;
    background-color: #0088FF; /*0088FF*/
    color: #ffffff; 
}
.navBarWidth{
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.navBarStyles li{
    float: left;
    }
.navBarStyles li a{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: .9em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navBarMain li a:hover{
    background-color: #40A5FF; /*#005569 #3D3C3C  12B0CC*/
    text-shadow: none;
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transition-property: background-color;
    -moz-transition-duration: .30s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    /* WebKit */
    -webkit-transition-property: background-color;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .30s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    /* Opera */
    -o-transition-property: background-color;
    -o-transition-duration: .30s;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    /* Standard */
    transition-property: background-color;
    transition-duration: .30s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

.navBarExtended li a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    background: none;
}


/*Class applied to current page element */
.onSelect{
    background-color: #40A5FF;
}

/*Navigation Bar Extra - Sytles*/
.navBarExtra li{
    float: right;
    opacity: .88;
}
.navBarExtra li:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-transition-property: opacity;
    -moz-transition-duration: .30s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
}

.dropdown{
    font-family: 'opensans-regular';
    font-size: .95em;
}

.navBarExtra ul li{
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
    min-width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
.navBarExtra ul li:hover > ul,
.navBarExtra ul li ul:hover{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Uejn/1/)

but not able to display the sub items under dropdown button. How can I target the dropdown button to display those when user hovers over `dropdown` button?

Comment: Are you using JavaScript? Consider using jQuery. Also, consider using Bootstrap. It's great for this kind of thing.

Comment: no @rybo111, trying it out with css.

Comment: You'd at least have to use `onclick=""` which is JavaScript.

Comment: let me change my question for now.

Comment: Sorry but now you'll have to use `onhover=""` JavaScript. jQuery makes JavaScript very quick to code. You should look it up.

Comment: yes, but this is possible with css. So just want to stick with css.

Comment: I guess you could try this: http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/

Comment: your code is not well formatted. you have `ul`s inside `ul` directly. and some `li`s doesn't have closing tags.

Comment: As Ravimallya stated, your HTML structure is the problem. Fix it first and then go back to fixing the menu.

Comment: yes fixed the html, I was just being too lazy to do it. haha! thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, with all the complicated class names and styles involved in your example, it's hard to work out what needs fixing. I put together a simple example that you can edit to work however you like. Should be pretty self explanatory.

See on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Uejn/23/

HTML

```
<ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">page 2</a></li>
    <li>title 1
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">page 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">page 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">page 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>title 2
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">page 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">page 7</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.navbar, .navbar ul 
{                                               
    font-size:20px;
    list-style:none;
    z-index:10;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.navbar a, .navbar a:link
{               
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.navbar li          
{       
    float:left; 
    background: #666;
    width:100px;
}

.navbar li:hover, .navbar a:hover
{
    background:#aaa;  
    color:blue
}

.navbar li ul       
{   
    display:none;
}

.navbar li:hover ul
{   
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    width:100px;
}

.navbar li ul li 
{   
    float:none;

}
```

Comment: instead of using `<div class="navbar">` use `<ul class="navbar">`

Comment: That's right thanks, changed to ul